# Using one table as a reference point for another table's calculations

Tags: oracle

I am looking to use one table as a reference point for another table.  Table1 will have all of the parameters set and table2 contains a value that I need for a calculation.  I am looking for a way to reference table2's value based on a date and multiply table1's value by the value in table2.  I hope this example helps

**Table1**

```
 account1      datefrom1      dateto1     value1
    1234          01/01/18     12/31/18     5
    5678          01/01/17     12/31/17     6
    8912          01/03/17     12/31/18     7
    6543          02/01/18     12/31/18     8
```

**Table2**

```
 datefrom2      dateto2     value2
    01/01/18      12/31/18       1.02
    01/01/17      12/31/17       1.05
```

In this instance, I would like 1234 to return 5.1 (5*1.02) since it falls in the 1/1/18 - 12/31/18 range

I would also like 5678 to return 6.3 (6*1.05) since it falls in the 1/1/17 - 12/31/17 range

The same logic applies to 8912 and 6543

I appreciate any help

Comment: That's very simple examples. Will the ranges always match exactly like you are showing? Or can they overlap like in 01/07/17-30/06/18? How to calculate then?

Comment: Datefrom1 would not always identically match datefrom2.  I will add in an example.  In most cases they should, but there will be exceptions.

There would not be any overlap.

Comment: With always only one table2 record matching, this is still a simple inner join. Think of which conditions must be met in order to find the one table2 record for a table 1 record. Which condition must table2.datefrom2 meet? Which condition must table2.dateto2 meet? Take Aleksej's answer and change the ON clause accordingly.

Comment: I see.  Thank you very much for the help.  I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More a comment that an answer: if you only have to relate records for which both `dateFrom` and `dateTo` exactly match, you simply need a JOIN:

```
select t1.account1, t1.datefrom1, t1.dateto1, t1.value1 * t2.value2 as val
from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2
        on(t1.datefrom1 = t2.datefrom2 and t1.dateto1 = t2.dateto2)
```

If your relation is not so easy, for example relating records where dates overlap, please add some more details and a wider set of sample data.

Besides, what if a record in one of your tables has no corresponding record in the other one? Do you want to get it? If so, how to calculate the value?